# Add more value affter json endcode

Tags: php

```
$response = array(
    "aaData" => $data

);

echo json_encode($response);
```

how to add more name = '123', data = $data

Comment: Add it to the data element, _before_ you encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push data into the array or you can define the array and assign value by  key
Example

```
   $response = [];
   $response['name'] = '123';
   $response['data'] = 'mydata';
   $response['aaData'] = $data;

   echo json_decode($response);
```

$data can be array like this

```
   $data =[];
   $data['name'] = "ABCD";
   $data['id'] = 1;
   $response['aaData'] = $data;
```

By loop

```
 $dataTableResponse = [];
 for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++) {
  $data['name'] = "A";
  $data['id'] = $i;
  $dataTableResponse[] = $data;
 }
  $response['aaData'] = $dataTableResponse;
   echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I want aaData to be the outermost key of the json, which contains $data, name and something else to use for the DataTable

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side check this